# Unexpected end of Json Input Ionic 3 & Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular6

I saw many topics about this error but I could not find any solution to mine. I woke up in this morning and served my code and I saw that the error "Unexpected end of Json Input" I changed nothing in my code or versions of my packages. My colleague and I are working on this project and same codes are working well on his computer although we have same packages and versions.

Problem is when I request the server , it response "status 200 ok" but it returns empty "_body" as you see below image.

[image]

Here are details of the error :

[image]

The sample code is;

```
     console.log(localStorage.getItem("usedURL"));
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();

        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        this.http.post(localStorage.getItem("usedURL")+"/login", JSON.stringify({ "UserName": credentials.email, "Password": credentials.password }), { headers: headers})
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
                resolve(res.json());
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
```

However I believe that it is not releated with code. So I tried to clean cache , deleting node modules and re-installing it. Copied all codes from my colleague to my computer but issue has never gone. So anybody has any idea how can I fix this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, are you `http` or `httpclient`? Secondly,  why did you wrap a promise over http request? Thirdly, if you want to return promise, you could simply convert your http request observable to promise by using `.toPromise()` https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html.

Comment: I am using http. I am getting this error in my every provider so nothing changed when I convert this observeble or write as .toPromise() version.

Comment: you should be using `HttpClientModule` instead of `HttpModule` since you are using angular6 https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Chrome are you using now? If you using latest version just try downgrade your version :). You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks mate!! This solved my problem. You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see the images,

**Response;**

```
Response {_body: "", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: "http://myapiurl//login"
_body:"" 
__proto__: Body
```

**Detail of the error;**

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (account-auth-service.ts:109)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:242)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:189)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
```

Comment: you don't have to write your question as an answers here.. :) you can just edit the question

Comment: Thanks for the advise :). I hope you have an idea about the question too :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is correct with the response you are getting.

By that I mean that your response body is "", and if you try to `JSON.parse("")` you will the error you are getting. i.e.,

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

So now we found out that the error you are getting is because of the response you are getting. Now we need to know why your API is returning blank string? we don't know since you have not pasted your API login code. Either way you will need to edit your question and add your API login code or create a new question.